# I tried installing oracle but it was showing installation error. Will there be some residues of failed installation files on my system?

Tags: windows-10, installation

The error to be specific is this
""The wizard was interrupted before oracle Database 18c Express Edition could be installed

Your system has not been modified. To complete installation at another time, please run  setup again". I am installing it in an external hard drive

Comment: The full Oracle DB is huge, and there may indeed be some settings left in Registry or files that have not been deleted. Why would this be a concern? Only if it were to interfere with a subsequent attempt to install would I bother to remove small remnants. For that matter, you might have better luck with the full DB, free for personal and educati0onal use: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle-database-software-downloads.html

Comment: Which executable are you running?